# how can I use viewbag without affecting the name of dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use a viewbag but I don't want to affect the name of the dropdown. I want a different name to use in dropdown. is it possible or It has another solution.

My Codes in View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.concurring1 = TempData["pathologistlist"];
 }                            
@Html.DropDownList("concurring", "Select Pathologist")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.Object%29) of DropDownList helper method which allows you to generate the SELECT element with custom name and id value

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code will be

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyCustomName",ViewBag.concurring as List<SelectListItem>,"Select one")
```

Assuming there is a ViewBag entry exist for `concurring` which is of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

```
var list= new List<SelectListItem>{
   new SelectListItem { Value="MI", Text="Michigan" },
   new SelectListItem { Value="NY", Text="New York" }
};
ViewBag.concurring = list;
```

The above code will generate the SELECT element with name id value set to "`MycustomName`"

Comment: it says There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key MyCustomName

Comment: thanks for the answer but do you know how to add a hardcoded values together with the values from database in dropdown ?